# sendBroadcast with no registered receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

What happens to an intent if it is broadcast with no registered receivers currently present? Is it waiting in a queue until someone can receive it or is it just gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you send the broadcast.  For example if the code says:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AN_ACTION);
sendStickyBroadcast(intent);
```

The broadcast will be held by the system.

Whenever anyone registers to receive a sticky broadcast they receive the most recent one sent.

If the broadcast is not sticky, then, yes, it disappears if there are no registered receivers.

Comment: I actualy want to use sendOrderedBroadcast(). So i guess it will be gone with no memory issues, right ?

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you!